# function mysqli_result como se puede usar ahora?

Tags: php, mysqli, select, function

Me encuentro haciendo este código de un curso ya viejo
trato de actualizar el código para que sea funcional
pero no he sido capaz de arreglar este código

```
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("no se ha podido connectar...");
    mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "nueva");

    $por_pagina = 6;

    $pagina_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT('id') FROM usuários");
```

La dificultad es aca antes en el codigo se usaba el mysql_result, que quedaba algo

```
   $paginas = ceil (mysql_result($pagina_query, 0)/$por_pagina);
```

Para separar en este caso cada 6 usuarios
y generar la segunda pagina así el numero sea decimal

Con la única función que me retorna algo es con esta de abajo
pero sigue siendo solo 1, no recibe mas datos

```
     $paginas = ceil (mysqli_num_rows($pagina_query)/$por_pagina);
```

Hice esto

```
     function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
     $res->data_seek($row); 
     $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
     return $datarow[$field];
     } 

      $paginas = ceil(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_result ($pagina_query, 0)/$por_pagina));
```

Me retorna el valor que quiero pero no lo convierte a entero y sale fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1
> ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, float given inFatal error:
> Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must
> be of type mysqli_result, float given in

```
    $pagina =(isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

    $start = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT nombre FROM usuários LIMIT $start, $por_pagina");
    while($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    
    echo $query_row['nombre']."<br/>";
    
    }

    if($paginas >=1){
    
    for($x=1;$x<=$paginas;$x++){
        
        echo "<a href='?page='".$x."'>".$x."</a>";
        
    }
    
    
    }
```

Busco un ayuda que me permita solucionarlo , ya lo he intentado por medio de funciones, y me retorna el total de paginas pero no me permite pasar entre ellas, la verdad encerré todo ese código en una función

al final hice un echo para llamarla, pero no me funciona el cambio de pagina

nota: soy programador novato dispuesto a dale al código

Comment: Veamos así para empezar   $pagina_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT('id') FROM usuários");  solo te devuelve un valor el número de registros de usuarios (count('id') cuenta los id en la tabla). Cambia por   $pagina_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT 'id' FROM usuarios"); y tendrás todos los usuarios. El número de páginas está bien calculado con mysqli_num_rows.

Comment: muchas gracias pero no me funciona aun, si quito el count(id) ya no me retorna numero el cual con el count  si lo hace, en mi caso tengo 8 usuarios me da un 1.3, que deberia con el ceil convertirse a 2 hojas, me sale falta error Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, float given in D:\Programacion\xampp\htdocs\nueva2\paginacion.php:19 Stack trace: #0 D:\Programacion\xampp\htdocs\nueva2\paginacion.php(19): mysqli_num_rows(1.3333333333333) #1 {main} thrown in D:\Programacion\xampp\htdocs\nueva2\paginacion.php on line 19

Comment: le quite el count y le movi unas cosas y ya me rotorna 1.6  Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, float given in D:\Programacion\xampp\htdocs\nueva2\paginacion.php:19 Stack trace: #0 D:\Programacion\xampp\htdocs\nueva2\paginacion.php(19): mysqli_num_rows(0.16666666666667) #1 {main} thrown in D:\Programacion\xampp\htdocs\nueva2\paginacion.php on line 19 pero sigue siendo un fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Este código php te permite leer una tabla (clientes) y mostrar los registros agrupados, en este caso de 6 en 6
Para smplificar solo considero dos campos: idreg y nombre.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $pass) or die("no se ha podido connectar...");
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "mibase");
$por_pagina = 6;
$pagina_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT idreg, nombre FROM clientes");
$paginas = ceil (mysqli_num_rows($pagina_query)/$por_pagina);
$pagActual = 0;
while ($pagActual < $paginas){
    echo "<h1>Pagina $pagActual</h1><br>";
    $lineas = 0;
    while($lineas < $por_pagina and $fila = $pagina_query->fetch_assoc() )
        {
        echo $fila['idreg'].": ".$fila['nombre']."<br>";
        $lineas++;
        }
    $pagActual++;
}
```

El error que obtienes se debe a que mysqli_num_rows() usa como argumento el resultado de un mysqli_query . Esta función retorna el número de filas obtenidas después de hacer una consulta, por eso puedes usarla para calcular el número de páginas.
Ojo, este ejemplo te va a agrupar los resultados en grupos de 6, pero en una sola página.
Si quieres hacerlo en varias páginas yo usaría el SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT offset, numrows. Así le dices cuantos registros quieres leer (numrows, 6 en este caso) y donde debe empezar (el offset: 0 la primera página, 6 la segunda, 12 la tercera ...) Estos valores de offset se los pasarías en la url (paginar.php?pag=0) y los cogerías con $_GET.
Creo que con esto puedes empezar.

Comment: gracias agregue lo que me digite y quedo ya

Comment: <?php
 

   
  
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("no se ha podido connectar...");
 mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "nueva");
 
 $por_pagina = 5;
 $pagina_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id, nombre FROM usuários");
 $paginas = ceil (mysqli_num_rows($pagina_query)/$por_pagina);
 $pagActual = 0;
 
  $pagina =(isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

  $start = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id, nombre FROM usuários LIMIT $start, $por_pagina");

Comment: $lineas = 0;
   while($lineas < $por_pagina and $fila = $query->fetch_assoc() )
    {
    echo $fila['id'].": ".$fila['nombre']."<br>";
    
    $lineas++;
   
    }
  

  if($paginas >=1){
  
   for($x=1;$x<=$paginas;$x++){
    echo '<a href="?pagina='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
  }  
  
 }
 
 
   
 
 
  
 

 
?>